# Filtering on a Column Whose Number is Specified in Another Column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm looking for a better way to achieve what the code below does with a `for` loop. The goal is to create a dataframe (or matrix) where each row is a possible `n`-length sequence of `1`s and `0`s, followed by an `n+1`th column which contains a number corresponding to one of the previous columns that contains a `0`.

So in the `n == 3` case for example, we want to include a row like this:

```
1 0 0 2
```

but not this:

```
1 0 0 1
```

Here's the code I have now (assuming `n == 3` for simplicity):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- expand.grid(x = 0:1, y = 0:1, z = 0:1, target = 1:3, keep = FALSE)

for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$keep[row] <- df[row, df$target[row]] == 0
}

df <- df %>% 
  filter(keep == TRUE) %>%
  select(-keep)

head(df)

#    x y z target
# 1  0 0 0      1
# 2  0 1 0      1
# 3  0 0 1      1
# 4  0 1 1      1
# 5  0 0 0      2
# 6  1 0 0      2
# 7  0 0 1      2
# 8  1 0 1      2
# 9  0 0 0      3
# 10 1 0 0      3
# 11 0 1 0      3
# 12 1 1 0      3
```

Seems like there has to be a better way to do this, especially with `dplyr`. But I can't figure out how to use the value of `target` to specify the column to `filter` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, we can create a row/column index to filter values from the dataframe and keep rows where the extracted value is 0.

```
df[df[cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$target)] == 0, ]

#   x y z target
#1  0 0 0      1
#3  0 1 0      1
#5  0 0 1      1
#7  0 1 1      1
#9  0 0 0      2
#10 1 0 0      2
#13 0 0 1      2
#14 1 0 1      2
#17 0 0 0      3
#18 1 0 0      3
#19 0 1 0      3
#20 1 1 0      3
```

**data**

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:1, y = 0:1, z = 0:1, target = 1:3)
```